# A chromium thread using port no other than 443 or 80

Tags: networking, chromium

I tried `ss` command to know the status of `sockets` in my system (ubuntu `14.10` ),

```
$ ss
tcp    ESTAB      0      0         192.168.1.10:51492    74.125.236.200:https   
tcp    ESTAB      0      0         192.168.1.10:45436      184.24.9.251:http    
tcp    ESTAB      0      0         192.168.1.10:33349     74.125.236.68:https   
tcp    ESTAB      0      0         192.168.1.10:45285     74.125.236.34:https   
tcp    ESTAB      0      0         192.168.1.10:52029    74.125.169.216:https   
tcp    ESTAB      0      0         192.168.1.10:49125      184.24.9.251:https   
tcp    ESTAB      0      0         192.168.1.10:49340      74.125.68.94:https   
tcp    ESTAB      0      0         192.168.1.10:47748     74.125.236.65:https   
tcp    ESTAB      0      0         192.168.1.10:32845     199.59.150.46:https   
tcp    ESTAB      0      0         192.168.1.10:34511     103.20.92.129:https   
tcp    ESTAB      0      0         192.168.1.10:43233    74.125.200.188:5228    
tcp    ESTAB      0      0         192.168.1.10:52208    74.125.169.216:https   
tcp    ESTAB      0      0         192.168.1.10:41742    184.87.213.124:http    
tcp    ESTAB      0      0         192.168.1.10:43939     74.125.68.147:https   
tcp    ESTAB      0      0         192.168.1.10:36935     74.125.236.90:http    
tcp    ESTAB      0      0         192.168.1.10:48165     74.125.236.33:https   
tcp    ESTAB      0      0         192.168.1.10:41456     74.125.236.34:http    
tcp    ESTAB      0      0         192.168.1.10:40549     74.125.236.90:https   
tcp    ESTAB      0      0         192.168.1.10:37934     122.175.190.8:http    
tcp    ESTAB      0      0         192.168.1.10:44557      31.13.79.112:https   
tcp    ESTAB      0      0         192.168.1.10:49879     74.125.236.43:https   
tcp    ESTAB      0      0         192.168.1.10:54648     23.34.240.214:http    
tcp    ESTAB      0      0         192.168.1.10:60101     74.125.236.67:https   
tcp    ESTAB      0      0         192.168.1.10:60836   108.160.165.173:http
```

and here in one of output I got

```
tcp    ESTAB      0      0         192.168.1.10:43233    74.125.200.188:5228
```

then I tried `nslookup` ,I got

```
anupam@JAZZ:~$ nslookup 74.125.200.188
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
188.200.125.74.in-addr.arpa name = sa-in-f188.1e100.net.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

I am not getting `188.200.125.74.in-addr.arpa   name = sa-in-f188.1e100.net`.part here
,,

then I tried `netstat` to know the PID associated with this..

```
$ netstat -natp
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:60081      74.125.236.73:443       ESTABLISHED 5141/chromium-brows
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:54746      74.125.236.199:80       ESTABLISHED 5141/chromium-brows
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:32845      199.59.150.46:443       ESTABLISHED 5141/chromium-brows
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:55852      74.125.236.67:80        ESTABLISHED 5141/chromium-brows
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:43119      198.252.206.25:443      ESTABLISHED 5141/chromium-brows
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:43233      74.125.200.188:5228     ESTABLISHED 5141/chromium-brows
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:41044      74.125.130.104:443      ESTABLISHED 5141/chromium-brows
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:56479      74.125.236.196:443      ESTABLISHED 5141/chromium-brows
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:48165      74.125.236.33:443       ESTABLISHED 5141/chromium-brows
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:35692      74.125.236.74:443       ESTABLISHED 5141/chromium-brows
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:60101      74.125.236.67:443       ESTABLISHED 5141/chromium-brows
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:60836      108.160.165.173:80      ESTABLISHED 2919/dropbox    
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:52425      74.125.236.201:443      ESTABLISHED 5141/chromium-brows
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:60058      74.125.236.73:443       ESTABLISHED 5141/chromium-brows
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.10:40360      74.125.130.94:443       ESTABLISHED 5141/chromium-brows
```

Here I found that It was thread of `PID` `5141` ,in `chromium` browser ,,

My question is as browsers are just user interface for `http` or `https` protocol implementation to exchange html pages ,, how any thread of it can use port no other than `80` or `443`..(`43233` here) ??

Comment: FYI 1e100.net is a google domain - https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/174717?hl=en

Comment: Thanx @NCRhodes ,, but for browser related requests it should use ports (80 or 443) but here it has used 5228 (74.125.200.188:5228).

Answer (score 2):

> There are 2 ports: a **source port** (browser) and a **destination port** (server). The browser asks the OS for an available source port (let's say it receives **33123**) then makes a socket connection to the destination port (usually **80/HTTP**, **443/HTTPS**).
>
> When the the web server receives the answer, it sends a response that has 80 as source port and 33123 as destination port.
>
> So if you have 2 browsers concurrently accessing stackoverflow.com, you'd have something like this:
>
> ```
> Firefox (localhost:33123) <-----------> stackoverflow.com (69.59.196.211:80)
> Chrome  (localhost:33124) <-----------> stackoverflow.com (69.59.196.211:80)
> ```

[Source - Stack Overflow, Flavius Stef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957757/how-can-an-application-use-port-80-http-without-conflicting-with-browsers)

Comment: thanx @Tim ,well had doubt regarding port no. by which server listen's . Is it possible to have Firefox (localhost:33123) <-------->stackoverflow.com(69.59.196.211:33455(any port no other than 80 or 443)

Comment: No. Typically the webserver port is 80 and the https server is 443. For example, my website (http://hitchins.tk) you can see that I have the post 80 enabled in my 000-defaukt.conf http://paste.ubuntu.com/9255873/

Comment: You can add other ports for other things, but a typical request won't have that.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the source code of chromium-browser version `65.0.3325.181-0ubuntu1.debian`.

```
# google_apis/gcm/engine/gservices_settings.cc
const char kDefaultCheckinURL[] = "https://android.clients.google.com/checkin";
const char kDefaultMCSHostname[] = "mtalk.google.com";
const int kDefaultMCSMainSecurePort = 5228;
const int kDefaultMCSFallbackSecurePort = 443;
// ...
GURL GServicesSettings::GetMCSMainEndpoint() const {
  // ...
  return GURL(MakeMCSEndpoint(kDefaultMCSHostname, kDefaultMCSMainSecurePort));
}
```

Looks like chromium is connecting to some google services on port 5228.